# C# Fluent API: How to construct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently, I'm creating custom MVC Html Helpers which I will be using through a fluent API.
To give an example to understand it, I'll have the following helper which is (or should be in a not too distant future) generate a grid:

```
@(Html.GridFor(Model)
  .WithName("MyName")
  .WithColumns(model =>
  {
      model.Bind(x => x.Name);
      model.Bind(x => x.DateCreated);
      model.Bind(x => x.DateUpdated);
  }).Render());
```

Now, everything is constructed with the start point. The IGridBuilder.

```
/// <summary>
///     When implemented by a class, it defines the class as an object that can construct a grid by using a fluent API.
/// </summary>
public interface IGridBuilder<TModel> : IHtmlHelper, IDataSource<TModel>
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the name of the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" />.
    /// </summary>
    string Name { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Sets the name of the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" />. This name will be used as an id on the outer element that
    ///     holds the entire grid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name that the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" /> should have.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" /> that can be used to construct the grid through a fluent API.</returns>
    IGridBuilder<TModel> WithName(string name);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Set the columns of the model that should be bound to grid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bindAllColumns">The action that will bind all the columns.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" /> that is used to construct the grid.</returns>
    IGridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<IColumnBinder<TModel>> bindAllColumns);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Renders the grid with all the set properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="MvcHtmlString" /> that contains the HTML representation of the grid.</returns>
    MvcHtmlString Render();

    #endregion
}
```

and to make the bind commands, I'm using an IColumnBinder interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// When implemented by a class, this class is marked as being an builder that can construct a column through a fluent API.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
public interface IColumnBinder<TModel> : IHtmlHelper, IDataSource<TModel>
{
    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Binds an column to the grid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TItem">The type of the column on which to bind the items.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertySelector">The functional that will bind the control to the grid.</param>
    void Bind<TItem>(Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> propertySelector);

/// <summary>
///     Apply a specific css class on an element.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="className">The name of the css class that should be placed on the element.</param>
/// <returns>As <see cref="IColumnBinder{TModel}"/> that is used to construct this column through a fluent API.</returns>
IColumnBinder<TModel> WithCss(string className);

    #endregion
}
```

Now, what's the best approach to link an IColumnBuilder to an IGridBuilder?

To make it very short, I'm struggling with the following:

The IColumnBuilder set ups specific properties but the rendering takes place in the IGridBuilder interface.

The main problem lies in the following code:

```
/// <summary>
///     Set the columns of the model that should be bound to grid.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bindAllColumns">The action that will bind all the columns.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" /> that is used to construct the grid.</returns>
public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<IColumnBinder<TModel>> bindAllColumns)
{
    bindAllColumns(new ColumnBinder<TModel>());

    return this;
}
```

So here I execute the action to bind the column:

```
model.Bind(x => x.Name)
```

But how can I keep a reference between the IGridBuilder and the IColumnBuilder to construct it in a proper way afterwars?

Or are there other solutions?

Comment: You posted the same code section twice

Comment: Do you use any IoC-container?

Comment: So it's updated. Yes I'm using Unity, but I don't see how an IoC container is linked to a fluent API.

Comment: If you use IoC-container, passing the instance into the constructor should be the most obvious solution. Unless you have no options to resolve this dependency from static class of HtmlHelper extensions.

Comment: I see what you mean but it's not an answer to the question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thatswhy i've written it down here, in comments :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok,

After hours of searching I've found a solution and therefore I'm answering my own question. However, if there are users that have another approach to the same problem, please tell me so I can adapt me code maybe.

This code will primarly use a class to transfer objects, since a class is a reference type it can be passed to another object, and that object can manipulate the object.

So, I have written a custom HTML helper that should work as the following:

```
@(Html.GridFor(Model)
  .WithName("MyName")
  .WithColumns(model =>
  {
      model.Bind(x => x.Name).WithCss("row first");
      model.Bind(x => x.DateCreated);
      model.Bind(x => x.DateUpdated);
  }).Render());
```

So, I do have a model that's enumerable and that I will pass to the grid. The grid takes 3 columns of the model and renders the grid.

For this code, I have a couple of interfaces which helps me throughout the process:

1. An HTML Helper interface (just holds an object to the HtmlHelper):

   ```
   /// <summary>
   ///     Provides a way to extend the <see cref="HtmlHelper" /> to construct objects of various kinds.
   /// </summary>
   public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
   {
       #region Grid

       /// <summary>
       ///     Constructs a grid for a property that holds a collection.
       /// </summary>
       /// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model on which this grid is being build.</typeparam>
       /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type of a single item in the collection.    </typeparam>
       /// <param name="htmlHelper">The helper on which this method is executed.    </param>
       /// <param name="dataSource">The datasource on which the items are bound.    </param>
       /// <returns>An <see cref="IGridBuilder{TEntity}" /> that is used to construct the grid.</returns>
       public static IGridBuilder<TEntity> GridFor<TModel, TEntity>(this     HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
           IEnumerable<TEntity> dataSource)
       {
           return new GridBuilder<TEntity>(htmlHelper, dataSource);
       }

       #endregion
   }
   ```
2. A Datasource interface (just holds an interface to the datasource):

   ```
   public interface IDataSource<out TModel>
   {
       #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets the source that will be bound to the implemented object.
        /// </summary>
        IEnumerable<TModel> DataSource { get; }

        #endregion
   }
   ```

And then we have all the other code.

1. The HTML Helper extension class is the first one:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   ///     Provides a way to extend the <see cref="HtmlHelper" /> to construct objects of various kinds.
   /// </summary>
   public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
   {
       #region Grid

       /// <summary>
       ///     Constructs a grid for a property that holds a collection.
       /// </summary>
       /// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model on which this grid is being build.</typeparam>
       /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type of a single item in the collection.</typeparam>
       /// <param name="htmlHelper">The helper on which this method is executed.</param>
       /// <param name="dataSource">The datasource on which the items are bound.</param>
       /// <returns>An <see cref="IGridBuilder{TEntity}" /> that is used to construct the grid.</returns>
       public static IGridBuilder<TEntity> GridFor<TModel, TEntity>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
           IEnumerable<TEntity> dataSource)
       {
           return new GridBuilder<TEntity>(htmlHelper, dataSource);
       }

       #endregion
   }
   ```
2. Then the next one is an implementation of the IGridBuilder interface:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   ///     Provides an implemention of the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" /> that is used to construct the grid through a
   ///     fluent API.
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model that the grid will hold.</typeparam>
   public class GridBuilder<TModel> : IGridBuilder<TModel>
   {
       #region Constructors

       /// <summary>
       ///     Creates a new instance of the <see cref="GridBuilder{TModel}" />.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="helper">The <see cref="HtmlHelper" /> that is used to construct the grid.</param>
       /// <param name="dataSource">The collection of objects that will be bound to the grid.</param>
       public GridBuilder(HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<TModel> dataSource)
       {
           htmlHelper = helper;
           DataSource = dataSource;
           Constructor = new GridConstructor<TModel>(htmlHelper, DataSource);
       }

       #endregion

       #region IGridBuilder Members

       /// <summary>
       ///     Gets the name of the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" />.
       /// </summary>
       public string Name { get; private set; }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Gets the constructor that will be used to construct this <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" />.
       /// </summary>
       public IGridContructor<TModel> Constructor { get; set; }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Gets the source that will be bound to the implemented object.
       /// </summary>
       public IEnumerable<TModel> DataSource { get; private set; }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Gets the <see cref="HtmlHelper" /> object.
       /// </summary>
       public HtmlHelper htmlHelper { get; private set; }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Sets the name of the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" />. This name will be used as an id on the outer element that
       ///     holds the entire grid.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="name">The name that the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" /> should have.</param>
       /// <returns>An <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" /> that can be used to construct the grid through a fluent API.</returns>
       public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithName(string name)
       {
           Name = name;
           return this;
       }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Set the columns of the model that should be bound to grid.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="bindAllColumns">The action that will bind all the columns.</param>
       /// <returns>An <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}" /> that is used to construct the grid.</returns>
       public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<IColumnBinder<TModel>> bindAllColumns)
       {
           var columnBinder = new ColumnBinder<TModel>(Constructor);

           bindAllColumns(columnBinder);
           return this;
       }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Renders the grid with all the set properties.
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns>A <see cref="MvcHtmlString" /> that contains the HTML representation of the grid.</returns>
       public MvcHtmlString Render()
       {
           var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

           BaseElementBuilder parentElement = DivFactory.DivElement().WithCss("header");

           outputBuilder.Append(parentElement.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
           outputBuilder.Append(parentElement.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));

           return new MvcHtmlString(outputBuilder.ToString());
       }

       #endregion
   }
   ```
3. Then an implementation of the IGridColumnBinder:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   ///     Provides an implementation of the <see cref="IColumnBinder{TModel}" /> that can be used to construct a column
   ///     through a fluent API.
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the datasource that's bound to the grid.</typeparam>
   public class ColumnBinder<TModel> : IColumnBinder<TModel>
   {
       #region Constructors

       /// <summary>
       ///     Creates a new instance of the <see cref="ColumnBinder{TModel}" />.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="constructor">An <see cref="IGridContructor{TModel}" /> that contains the builder to construct the grid.</param>
       public ColumnBinder(IGridContructor<TModel> constructor)
       {
           Constructor = constructor;
       }

       #endregion

       #region IColumnBinder Members

       /// <summary>
       ///     Gets the values that are bound to this <see cref="IColumnBinder{TModel}" />.
       /// </summary>
       public IGridContructor<TModel> Constructor { get; private set; }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Gets the css class of the <see cref="IColumnBinder{TModel}" />.
       /// </summary>
       public string CssClass { get; private set; }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Gets the values that are bound to this <see cref="IColumnBinder{TModel}" />.
       /// </summary>
       public IList<object> Values { get; set; }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Binds an column to the grid.
       /// </summary>
       /// <typeparam name="TItem">The type of the column on which to bind the items.</typeparam>
       /// <param name="propertySelector">The functional that will bind the control to the grid.</param>
       /// <returns>As <see cref="IColumnBinder{TModel}" /> that is used to construct this column through a fluent API.</returns>
       public IColumnBinder<TModel> Bind<TItem>(Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> propertySelector)
       {
           string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(propertySelector);
           name = Constructor.htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);

           ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(() => default(TModel),
               typeof (TModel), name);

           // Get's the name to display on the column in grid. The Display attribute is used if present, otherwise the name of the property is used.
           string displayName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(metadata.DisplayName)
               ? metadata.PropertyName
               : metadata.DisplayName;

           Values =
               Constructor.DataSource.Select(myVar => propertySelector.Compile()(myVar))
                   .Select(dummy => (object) dummy)
                   .ToList();

           Constructor.builderProperties.Add(displayName, this);
           return this;
       }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Apply a specific css class on an element.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="className">The name of the css class that should be placed on the element.</param>
       /// <returns>As <see cref="IColumnBinder{TModel}" /> that is used to construct this column through a fluent API.</returns>
       public IColumnBinder<TModel> WithCss(string className)
       {
           CssClass = className;
           return this;
       }

       #endregion
   }
   ```
4. And as last the implementation of the IGridConstructor.

   ```
   /// <summary>
   ///     Provides an implemention of the <see cref="IGridContructor{TModel}" /> that is used to construct the grid through a
   ///     fluent API.
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the model that the grid will hold.</typeparam>
   public class GridConstructor<TModel> : IGridContructor<TModel>
   {
       #region Constructors

       /// <summary>
       ///     Creates a new instance of the <see cref="GridConstructor{TModel}" />.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="helper">The <see cref="HtmlHelper" /> that is used to built the model.</param>
       /// <param name="source">The model that is bound to the grid.</param>
       public GridConstructor(HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<TModel> source)
       {
           htmlHelper = helper;
           DataSource = source;

           builderProperties = new Dictionary<string, IColumnBinder<TModel>>();
       }

       #endregion

       #region Properties

       /// <summary>
       ///     Provides a dictionary that contains all the properties for the builder.
       /// </summary>
       public IDictionary<string, IColumnBinder<TModel>> builderProperties { get; set; }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Gets the source that will be bound to the implemented object.
       /// </summary>
       public IEnumerable<TModel> DataSource { get; private set; }

       /// <summary>
       ///     Gets the <see cref="HtmlHelper" /> object.
       /// </summary>
       public HtmlHelper htmlHelper { get; private set; }

       #endregion
   }
   ```

Now, how does this works exactely?

1. The HtmlHelper returns an member that implements an IGridBuilder, so in the example above, it returns a GridBuilder.
2. On that GridBuilder, there are a couple of elements that you can call, and one more important is the WithColumns method that takes a IColumnBinder action and there's the trick. The implementation of IColumnBinder takes a reference to an IGridConstructor. And it's that constructor that will be fully built up.

So all the things we need to know for rendering, including each css class for a given column are exposed through the GridBuilder.GridContructor

So, a very vert long post, but I hope it helps some people.